# Alternating Series Test: must b_n be decreasing for all n or only for large n?

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

The alternating series test (AST) for a sequence $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n b_{n}$ stipulates that $\{b_{n}\}$ must be decreasing. [Paul's Online Math Notes](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/AlternatingSeries.aspx) say that $\{b_{n}\}$ must be decreasing for **large** $n$, while most other sources (e.g. [1](http://scipp.ucsc.edu/%7Ehaber/ph116A/altseries11.pdf), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test), [3](http://www.i-element.org/PDF/M01.pdf)) say that $\{b_{n}\}$ must be decreasing for **all** $n$.  Which of these is correct, and why?  An example would help to clarify this.

Comment: Source (1) that you linked to actually states correctly that the terms must be decreasing for large $n$ (it says "for all $n\ge n_0$"), not for all $n$.

Comment: @zipirovich thank you, I think I misunderstood the notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter since converegence of a series is determined only by the behaviour at the tails, i.e. large $n$. Any truncation of the series at a finite $N$ will be a finite number...

Comment: That makes sense to me, but then why would all these sources, including James Stewart's calculus textbook, imply that it does matter?

Comment: How do they imply it?

Comment: "The $b_n$ are monotonically decreasing in magnitude for all $n ≥ n_0$. That is, $|b_{n+1}| ≤ |b_n|$ for all $n > n_0$"

Comment: That's effectively a restatement of my answer. It doesn't  matter at all....

Comment: I think I misunderstand the notation.  Could you explain the notation?

Comment: Regardless, Stewart says "$b_{n+1} \leq b_n$ for all $n$.  If this is technically incorrect, I imagine he must have a purpose to it. What could this purpose be?

Comment: Its not incorrect. Just unnecesarily restrictive.